# how to transform a writedable stream to a readable one and upload on a S3 bucket with nodejs

Tags: javascript, stream

I'm trying to create a stream file and directly upload it on my aws s3. But every time i get this error

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
Error: Uncaught error: Cannot pipe. Not readable.
    at WriteStream.Writable.pipe (_stream_writable.js:162:22)
    at generateSvg.then.upload.on.upload.on (/Users/paulette/Desktop/apilogostudio/lib/api/logo.js:112:11)
    at /Users/paulette/Desktop/apilogostudio/lib/api/logo.js:159:14
    at _fulfilled (/Users/paulette/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/paulette/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/paulette/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /Users/paulette/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (/Users/paulette/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/paulette/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (node.js:370:9)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:425:11)
```

Do you have any ideas :-D ?